# Session timeout after period of inactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have an application that requires a login and I also have an AJAX timer. I have read several posts on how to create a session timeout after a certain period of time. However, I want the session to end if the user hasn't clicked a certain button for say, 5 minutes. Is there a way to reset the timer after every click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function logout() { 
    location.href = '/your/logout/page.aspx';
}

var timeout = setTimeout(300000, logout);
function resetTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(300000, logout);
}

document.onclick = resetTimeout;
```

Comment: +1. To managing timer sample. Note that you may need to call resetTimeout in other places where you detect "activity", also onclick may not reach document if handled earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a javascript timer on the page load (with setTimeout) and that would get reset with each post-back (and optionally by a button click that does NOT post back), and when that timer counts down to zero it would redirect to a logout.aspx (ex: window.location='Logout.aspx') that handles clearing the session and then redirects back to the Login page.