# redirect user after period of inactivity

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-timeout

I'm using asp.net 4.0 with vb.net backend.

I am not using Forms.Authentication as the user is coming in via SSO. What I would like to do is after a period of no activity, redirect the user to a "Session Timout" page. I've struggled finding examples online as most reference the forms.authenticate scenario. I've attempted to perform a redirect in the Session_End but have since learned about the state of the http protocol at that time. What I am seeing is, if the session_ends and then the user attempts an action, the session_start is being called before the subsequent call to Page-Load so I cannot check the sessionID at that time because it will contain a value.

Can I implement Forms.authenticate transparently to the user in order to take advantage of this functionality? Or is this something that I should handle with a javascript timer or something, like this:

[Session timeout after period of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632059/session-timeout-after-period-of-inactivity)

Any ideas. At a lost to say the least.

Thanks

Comment: put some javascript that after someperiod redirect to the page you says

Comment: I'm not sure what you think forms.authenticate will do for you here.  If you just want the page to auto redirect once a timeout period has been reached then you have to do that client side.  Meaning, you have to use javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. JS is the way to go. I appreciate it.